# Deleted email re-appears in inbox after it has been deleted in Mail app

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, email, catalina

After upgrading to Catalina on my MacBook Pro, I noticed that deleted emails re-appear in my in box after a few minutes after the deletion. The only way I can really delete them is by using my iPad or my phone to delete them. At least they don't re-appear if I use any of those devices.

Is this an introduced bug in the Catalina version of Mac mail? Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug.  Do you have more than 1 mailbox in Mail?  If so, is this happening to all mailboxes?  How do you have this mailbox setup (POP or IMAP)?

Comment: One user fixed this on their iPhone by removing and re-adding the account.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. 
I have only 1 Google account set up in the mail app. I removed it and added it again and the issue went away. Thank you for that very useful tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I removed [the google account] and added it again and the issue went away.

System Preferences → Internet Accounts, remove the troubling IMAP account and add it back. For a less drastic measure, uncheck the Mail checkbox and tick it again.

Comment: The unchecking / rechecking the Mail checkbox didn't help, only complete removing of the account from the preferences and then adding it back